# apache2 mod ssl does not respond to wan request

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, https, web

WAN =====> router (interface WAN1 setup with my public ip) ==> NAT incoming 443 connection to ====> Apache2 Web server

apache2 is configured with one virtual host on port listening on mysite.com on port 443

**The problem:**

my /etc/hosts file say:

```
172.16.xxx.xxx mysite.com
```

so i open the browser and after typing *https://mysite.com* all goes fine, server respond on specified virtual host with https protocol.

Now i want to try connect to the server using my public ip.

updated /etc/hosts file now say:

```
xxpublicipxx mysite.com
```

When i open the browser i got a timeout error. My router firewall show that 443 connections are accepted

When i used private ip into my /etc/hosts file, server's netstat commad, after an https request, said:

```
Proto Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       PID/Program   name</br>
tcp6  172.16.xxx.xxx:https    172.16.xxx.xxx.57154    ESTABLISHED www-data   8105/apache2
```

and that's fine.

When i updated hosts with my public ip i got

```
Proto  Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       PID/Program
tcp    172.16.10.20:https      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53618 SYN_RECV    root       -
```

Connections stuck in SYN_RECV and on client side i got a timeout error, and as you see no PID/Program.

Any advice?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

My router is a Zyxel ZyWALL USG 100. 
In order to get a working WAN connection a Policy Route must be set.

Using the web interface:

```
Configuration -> Network -> Routing -> Policy Route -> +Add

User: any
Incoming: any (Exluding ZyWALL)
Source Address: any
Destination address: ***LAN IP OF YOUR NAT(ted) LAN SERVER
DSCP Code: any
Schedule: none
Service: HTTPS
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a routing problem.  The client sends a SYN to connect to the server; the server receives it and sends its ACK; but the client never receives the ACK.  A wireshark session would confirm that.  The fact that it works with the LAN IP address but not with the public IP address also strongly suggests that the router is at fault.

It's hard to say for sure what's wrong in the router configuration, but a reasonable guess is that it's sending the ACK out through the WAN interface, so it never reaches the client.  In other words, the router's NAT is broken.

Are you able to connect to the server from outside of the LAN?

Comment: Cool.  Can you give us a short summary?  Might help someone later.